# Poster Plugin with Autohot key

Tags: httprequest, autohotkey

am trying to create a GUI with autohotkey for a poster request using autohotkey.

for Ex:

```
{
"hwId":"2703",
"clientApiVersion":"1.0.0",
"sellId":"123456",
"uid":"123456",
"targetUserId":"123456",
"templateId":"123456",
"overrideValues": [{"name":"USERNAME","value":"test"}],
"customMessages": [{"name":"key1","value":"value1"},{"name":"key2","value":"value2"}],
"language":"en",
"verificationCode":"code",
"badge":"33",
}
```

this is the poster body that i use. these are inputs that go in and the output is shown. usally when i send a POST request i get a response in json. Can some on help me with this... i tried searching the web but could not find anything that is relevant to the poster plugin with autohotkey.

Kindly help me guys.

Following is the code that i used

```
    #NoEnv
#SingleInstance, Force

;InputBox, pass, Password, Enter password.
URL := "https://examplesite.com/exchange/api/ios/sendPushNotificationTemplateByUid"
;PostData := "username=Pulover&password=" pass
PostData := "
(
hwId=2703,
clientApiVersion=1.0.0,
sellId=865895,
uid=573675618,
targetUserId=573675618,
templateId=78,
language=en,
verificationCode=code,
badge=50,
)"
oHTTP := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
;Post request
oHTTP.Open("POST", URL , False)
;Add User-Agent header
oHTTP.SetRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)")
;Add Referer header
oHTTP.SetRequestHeader("Referer", URL)
;Add Content-Type
oHTTP.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/JSON")
;Send POST request
oHTTP.Send(PostData)
;Get received data
Gui, Add, Edit, w800 r30, % oHTTP.ResponseText
Gui, Show
return
GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

Comment: Where do you have problems? Show us your code!

Answer (score 1):

The example body is written in JSON. So I'm highly suggesting you to use a JSON lib. This is the one I've been using so far without any problems: http://pastebin.com/6EzQAHbH
Just save it as jsonParser.ahk in your scripts dir. I wrote you a pretty clean example of what I think you are looking for:

```
#Include jsonParser.ahk

url := "https://examplesite.com/exchange/api/ios/sendPushNotificationTemplateByUid"
username := "USERNAME"

Gui, Add, Edit, w800 r30 vResponseEdit
Gui, Show

body_AhkObj := {"hwId": "2703"
               ,"clientApiVersion": "1.0.0"
               ,"sellId": "123456"
               ,"uid": "123456"
               ,"targetUserId": "123456"
               ,"templateId": "123456"
               ,"overrideValues": [{"name":username,"value":"test"}]
               ,"customMessages": [{"name":"key1","value":"value1"}, {"name":"key2","value":"value2"}]
               ,"language": "en"
               ,"verificationCode": "code"
               ,"badge": "33"}

;change the sellId after the object was created

body_AhkObj.sellId := "987654321"

;;;;;;;;

body_JsonCode := BuildJson(body_AhkObj)

WinHttpObj := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
WinHttpObj.Open("POST", url)
WinHttpObj.SetRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)")
WinHttpObj.SetRequestHeader("Referer", url)
WinHttpObj.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/JSON")
WinHttpObj.Send(body_JsonCode)

GuiControl,, ResponseEdit, % WinHttpObj.ResponseText

Return

GuiClose:
  ExitApp
Return
```

Comment: Awsm!... Thank you so much forivin... it worked like a charm..!!!  thank you so much... :)

Comment: Hi Forivin... the above code worked like charm... but is it possible to give the inputs of the json body before the code

For Example in the above code the value of the sellId in the json is hard coded is it possible to give the value of the sellId before the  code runs... Takeing the values and appending it in the json body?

Comment: Hi forivin.... thank you so much for you help... i managed to do this on my own...!! and it worked... :)

Comment: I changed my code to show you how you should do it. As long as you want to be able to change the values, don't call BuildJson(). I haven't tested the changed code.

Comment: Hi there forivin... sorry to bug you again... the json parser that you gave me earlier isnt working anymore... its weird that it worked few weeks back and now it says "Line Text: for k in obj {" This line does not contain a recognized action. cant figure out the why is this error coming.

Comment: Redownload the json library and replace it with your old one. Update your autohotkey. (Make sure to have Autohotkey_L): http://ahkscript.org/download/ahk-install.exe